# SignUp with Fingerprint result and use it for LogIn

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, fingerprint

I am looking for solution to save result of the Fingerprint autenticate on server and check on following scans if it is same device, based on some info i saved before.

Target behavior:

1. User fill up SignUp form (Name,Login, Password) and run Fingerprint autentication to bind this device and to allow fast LogIn.
2. Here i need to send to server something that i can check for future fingerprint uses to recognize this device and binded user.
3. When user LogIn with Fingerprint i should send result key to server and check if this device is bind to some user.

What could I use to implement such behavior?
Is it even possible?
Thank you

Comment: In java you could do it as this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40552412/how-does-fingerprint-authentication-work-in-mobile

Comment: Thank you! Very similar to what i was looking for. Is it work same way with iOS to?

Comment: Sorry don't know iOS